# Java How to convert a stream of stringified points to an ArrayList<Point2D.Double>

Tags: java, java-stream, data-conversion

I have a stream `Stream<String>` of stringified points like above:

> ("1,2","1,3", "3,4")

and I want to convert them into an `ArrayList<Point2D.Double>`

I am converting them to a `Stream<DoubleStream>`

```
Stream<DoubleStream> pointList = pointStrList.map(pointStr-> stream(pointStr.split(",")).mapToDouble(d->Double.valueOf(d)));
Stream<Point2D.Double> plist = pointList.map(val-> new Point2D.Double(val.toArray()[0], val.toArray()[1]));
```

but when I try to convert into an `ArrayList<Point2D.Double>` by dping:

```
ArrayList<Point2D.Double> array = plist.map(val->val);
```

It prompts me with an error:

```
Required type: ArrayList<Double> 
Provided: Stream<Object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your solution can't work when you do:

`val-> new Point2D.Double(val.toArray()[0], val.toArray()[1])`

`val` is a stream and you try to call `toArray()` twice on it. This does not work with Streams, when you do `val.toArray()` the first time, it consumes the Stream, and you can't use that stream again, therefore the second time you will get an exception. [See here for further explanations](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-operated-upon-or-closed-exception)

You can get the list directly this way:

```
List<Point2D.Double> pointList = pointStrList
       .map(pointStr -> pointStr.split(","))
       .map(a -> new Double[] {Double.parseDouble(a[0]), Double.parseDouble(a[1])})
       .map(a -> new Point2D.Double(a[0], a[1]))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- map each `String` to a `String[]` (split)
- map each `String[]` to a `Double[]` (parseDoule)
- map each `Double[]` to a `Point2D.Double`
- collect to a `List`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative (without any improvement) could be:

```
List<Point2D.Double> pointList = pointStrList
            .map(pointStr -> Stream.of(pointStr.split(",")))
            .map(a -> a.mapToDouble(Double::parseDouble).toArray())
            .map(a -> new Point2D.Double(a[0], a[1]))    
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```